# Retrieve JMS Headers right after the message is sent without consuming the message

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

How can I retrieve JMS Message headers after sending the message but without consuming the message ?

this is my message sending code

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(que, text, message -> {

       LOGGER.info("setting JMS Message header values");    
       message.setStringProperty(RequestContext.HEADER_ID, id);
     //  LOGGER.info(message.getJMSMessageId()); -- this gives a null value here
       return message;
 });
```

the message headers get generated only after the message is posted to the queue so iis there a simple way to retrieve JMS message headers when using MessagePostProcessor?

I've referred the links - [here](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-jms-setting-reading-header-properties-example/) and [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/remoting/30397-jmsmessageid-after-message-is-sent) but not much of help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the `JmsMessageID` header until the message is actually sent; the post processor just allows you to modify the converted message JUST BEFORE it is sent.

However, your second link should work ok, since it saves off a reference to the message which you can access later.

**EDIT**

Confirmed:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48001045Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48001045Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            final AtomicReference<Message> msg = new AtomicReference<>();
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar", m -> {
                msg.set(m);
                return m;
            });
            System.out.println(msg.get().getJMSMessageID());
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
ID:host.local-61612-1514496441253-4:1:1:1:1
```